# Apply a promition only on a product variation

Tags: commerce

I have a Drupal Commerce product with two variations.

- Variation A - 18 euro - SKU 123
- Variation B - 30 euro - SKU 234

Is it possible to apply a promotion only on *Variation B*?

I am using Drupal Commerce 8.x-2.4.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement you own promotion condition plugin. Theres a condition plugin defined in *commerce_product* module in Commerce module since 2.0 release but I recommend you to use latest stable release. Check this class `Drupal\commerce_product\Plugin\Commerce\Condition\OrderItemVariationType` thus it only checks for variation type (aka bundle), you can easily write your own checking specific product variation instance. Also worth checking *OrderItemProduct* condition plugin I think you need a mix from both. This plugin is located in the same namespace than the first one.

**Update**

There's a feature request for that [see this link](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2887061). Thanks to @bojanz!

Comment: Relevant feature request here: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce/issues/2887061

Comment: Nice! You guys are always ahead of the curve. Well @paul you got yourself a patch to work with.